# storing python output to file from cron

Tags: python, cron

I have the following python script that I am trying to run from cron and store its output.

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm  #pip3 install tqdm
x= range(1,20)
for _ in tqdm(x):
    time.sleep(0.2)

print("Done")
```

I tried some the following to store the output to file but only "Done" is is stored

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test && python3 tqdm_test.py >> test1.log
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test && /usr/bin/python3 tqdm_test.py &>> test2.log
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test && /usr/bin/python3 tqdm_test.py > test3.log
```

Ideally I want to store the progress bar + "Done" into the log file, any help is much appreciated. (I use Python 3.8.5 and Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tqdm` writes its progress indicator to stderr not stdout.

You were close with `&>>` however that failed because `&>>` (and the non-appending `&>`) are *bashisms*, whereas the default shell for cronjobs is /bin/sh.

You could set `SHELL=/bin/bash` inside your crontab, or redirect both stdout and stderr in /bin/sh using

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test && python3 tqdm_test.py >> test1.log 2>&1
```

(appending) or

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/test && python3 tqdm_test.py > test1.log 2>&1
```

(overwriting).

Comment: it works, can you please explain what is "2>&1"

Comment: @porgrammer3124 it says redirect file descriptor `2` (the standard error stream) to wherever file descriptor `1` (the standard output stream) is going (the file `test1.log`)